Can I handle Spring exceptions with an exception handler
I have build a spring boot 3 application and I want a global exceptions handler so that if any exception is thrown that a custom json message is returned. One of the things I want to prevent is if an endpoint has a path variable of type long and someone supplies a string then I get the following reponse:
{
    "type": "about:blank",
    "title": "Bad Request",
    "status": 400,
    "detail": "Failed to convert 'id' with value: 'as'",
    "instance": "/api/company/as"
}

I have added a global exception handle like this:
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
@ControllerAdvice
@Slf4j
public class GlobalExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleConflict(Exception ex) {
        log.error(ex.getMessage(), ex);

        return ResponseEntity.ok(ResponseDto.buildUnknownErrorResponse());
    }

}

However it doesn't execute if there is a spring exception thrown before the endpoint call for example if a url pathvariable or url doesnt exist.
How can I override the way spring handles exceptions?

Remove extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler, that also contains @ExceptionHandler and it will always try to match the best one, which is never your catch-all.

Controller advice can handle errors even before the endpoint method is executed, in your case when the parameter cannot be converted.
Try to change your GlobalExceptionHandler as below.
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler  {

  private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GlobalErrorHandler.class);

  @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
  public ResponseEntity<String> handleError(Exception ex) {
    log.error(ex.getMessage(), ex);

    return ResponseEntity.ok("Unknown error message.");
  }
}

ResponseEntityExceptionHandler handles all Spring MVC raised exceptions by default. If you extend this class, you can override specific exceptions like TypeMismatchException and keep predefined handlers for others. If you want global exception handler for all exceptions it doesn't make sense to extend this default Exception handler.

Thank you for your response. I got it to work by removing the "extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler". That really messed things up.
